# nhibernate transaction scope on a data import strategy

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions, data-import

We have a requirement to import a large amount of data between databases, with multiple tables involved.

What would be the best strategy for the transactions? I'm guessing opening a session, having one large transaction and commiting it at the end of the process would be a bad idea.

Would commiting after each table be better? What if a particular table had dependencies to other tables, how should that be handled?

Comment: If you're planning to use NHibernate for importing data, at the very least use `StatelessSession` for this.

Comment: I am not familiar with StatelessSession, I'm guessing it provides a faster method of inserting data?

Comment: Stateless sessions do not use a first level cache and do not use second level or query caches - http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-statelesssession Performance would be improved over Session for bulk operations (take a look at caveats for using stateless sessions however)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to import the tables without dependencies in separate transactions if possible, and then import tables with dependencies in another transaction.

If this is not possible I would recommend one big transaction.

Comment: Going back to database basics, when a transaction is created all the data that you intended to add to the database is stored in memory and is only added to the database once the commit has been called(?) In that scenario, wouldn't one large transaction potentially consume a large chunk of memory?

Comment: It would, but if you have a large amount of data you that need to be consistent, there aren't much else to be, except making sure yourself that data still are consistent

Comment: @user1838662 Somehow I find it dubious that modern advanced database systems wouldn't be capable of storing data to disk even before commit. Certainly different database engines might implement this differently. I suspect many will queue the data for disk writes while changes are made (but not wait for the write to complete until the prepare phase of the transaction).